# Как правильно определить скорость роста времени работы алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, сложность

Вот, дают задание такое, к которому есть такая формула:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы сказано, что нужно взять член с самой большой степенью, и тогда будет O(n^3), но! Если просто включить логику немного и подумать, то получается, что даже при n = 10.000, будет 10^9 - 10^10 - 10^6 + 3.
Едва ли это реальная функция сложности какого-либо алгоритма, но просто ради самой задачи. Ведь, пускай это будет сортировка, тогда массив длинной 10.000 элементов, это уже не мелочь. Даже если из 1.000.000 элементов, то получится 10^15 - 10^14 - 10^8 + 3, что тоже очень существенно.

Comment: В чем вопрос???

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, вопрос в заголовке.

Comment: 1)Не минус, а плюс, потому что если вы степень считаете циклом - то у вас два цикла - т.е. у вас все слагаемые будут с плюсом. 2) Операцию n^3 можно обьеденить с n^2 - тогда у вас будет одно слагаемое. Операция "+3" -  легкая, и не поджежит в даном случае сумированию, т.к. уйдет в процент равный "погрешности".

Comment: Ответ на заголовок: рассчитать по формуле, в основной части вопроса какой-то сумбур.

Comment: Считаются не сами величины, а условное время, которое затрачивается на их получение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сложность алгоритма - теоретическая математическая концепция, и, будучи таковой, должна использоваться именно так - при N, стремящемся к бесконечности. Возьмите N=гугол и посмотрите. Мало - берите гугоплекс.

Важно найти такое N<sub>0</sub> и С<sub>1</sub> и С<sub>2</sub>, что для всех N>N<sub>0</sub> выполнялось C<sub>1</sub>f(n) < T(n) < C<sub>2</sub>f(n).

Так что если даже я скажу, что для N<sub>0</sub> = 10<sup>100</sup> C<sub>1</sub> = 1/10000, а C<sub>2</sub> = 100000 - то этого вполне достаточно...

Не напоминайте того, гм... инженера, который доказывает, что все нечетные числа простые: 3, 5, 7... 9 - ну, погрешность эксперимента... 11, 13... Ну и хватит.

Вам в условии, кстати, никто и не говорит, что это количество операций или там время. Просто - есть такая **функция**, выразите ее в Θ-обозначениях.